# oracle sorts differently on simple order by and listagg's order by

Tags: oracle, listagg

Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

```
select letter from (
select 'A' as letter from dual union all
select 'Á' as letter from dual union all
select 'B' as letter from dual union all
select 'C' as letter from dual ) t
order by letter;
```

result (is okay):

```
A
Á
B
C
```

But with this

```
select listagg(letter,', ') within group (order by letter) from (
select 'A' as letter from dual union all
select 'Á' as letter from dual union all
select 'B' as letter from dual union all
select 'C' as letter from dual ) t;
```

the order of result letters are different:

```
A, B, C, Á
```

Is it a simple Oracle bug in the latter case?

(I don't say anything about NLS. I think these queries should work the same way independetly of NLS.)

**Update:**

Clarification:
I'm running these queries one-by-another in SqlDeveloper in the same connection.

```
NLS_SORT    HUNGARIAN
NLS_COMP    BINARY
```

(If @MT0's answer is the solution then IMHO it is a bug in oracle using different default NLS setting on a simple order by clause and on a listagg call.)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your NLS settings (particularly `NLS_SORT` and `NLS_COMP`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the `NLS_SORT` setting:

```sql
select listagg(letter,', ')
       within group (order by NLSSORT(letter, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_AI')) AS letters
from (
  select 'A' as letter from dual union all
  select 'Á' as letter from dual union all
  select 'B' as letter from dual union all
  select 'C' as letter from dual
) t;
```

Outputs:

> | LETTERS |
> | --- |
> | A, Á, B, C |

*Note: `LISTAGG` does not appear to use the session `NLS_SORT` setting in its `ORDER BY` clause; but you can pass it in directly as shown above.*

If you want to use the session parameter (rather than a specific value):

```sql
select listagg(letter,', ')
       within group (
         order by NLSSORT(
                    letter,
                    ( SELECT 'NLS_SORT='||value
                      FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                      WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_SORT' )
                  )
       ) AS letters
from (
  select 'A' as letter from dual union all
  select 'Á' as letter from dual union all
  select 'B' as letter from dual union all
  select 'C' as letter from dual
) t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7f48776bc1dd2e1fdfea3ba31b85cb6)*

Answer (score 1):

Ordering of letters depends critically on `NLS_SORT`, so what you say at the end of your message is perfectly wrong.

The main question is - are you getting those contradictory results on exactly the same system, with all the same NLS settings? If so, then that's a bug in the implementation of the `ORDER BY` clause in `LISTAGG`. It would be good to have a test case - show us your NLS settings (the result of `select * from v$nls_parameters`) followed immediately by the two queries and their outputs. For good measure, show also `select * from v$version` (telling us your database version).

Comment: "are you getting those contradictory results on exactly the same system, with all the same NLS settings" - yes, in the same connection, one-by-another.  "what you say at the end of your message is perfectly wrong" - I claimed that they're should work the same way relatively to each other, so I keep my statement --- of course the exact order is NLS dependant.

Comment: This answer is more of a comment than a solution. It is simple to replicate the OP's issue in multiple database versions [Oracle 11gR2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d3a54d5e6e9669526cd9dca7a7a609d3) [Oracle 18](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d3a54d5e6e9669526cd9dca7a7a609d3)

Comment: @Feri - The NLS setting thing is relevant in three ways: First, we needed to know that the results are obtained with the same NLS settings (which was not stated explicitly in the post). Second, it's possible that the bug (if indeed a bug) doesn't manifest itself for all choices of NLS_SORT, but only for some of them. Third, it is very helpful if we can replicate the anomaly on our own system; since on my system I didn't see the same behavior you reported, the whole thing depends clearly on NLS_SORT, and possibly also on Oracle version.

Comment: @MT0: the "answer" part is, "if everything is on the same system and with the same settings, then it's a bug". The rest is qualification - on my system I get the same results for both, so it's certainly not a universal bug. Of course, I could replicate the bug with different settings, but I find it a lot easier (and more relevant) to use the OP's settings. And, once confirmed, like you have, the question is completely answered by "it's a bug". The question was a yes or no question.